# How can I get a product object on another product page

Tags: handlebars.js, bigcommerce

I am attempting to show an accessory on a product page with Bigcommerce.

I have the ID of the accessories in a custom field as a list.

I need to be able to get a new product object for these ID's so that I can display a selection of additional products on the page.

I can see a handlebars expression of {{getObject}} but I am unable to make this access another product by id.

The current Bigcommerce additional products will not help us in this instance, I need to be able to reference other full product objects.

Comment: Have you looked into using a product pick list option for this? It's intended for "upsell" situations where an option selection is a separate product in its own right: https://support.bigcommerce.com/s/article/Options-SKUs-Rules#picklist . If that won't give you what you need, you'll probably need to make an ajax request for the product data using Stencil utils: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/adding-event-hooks-to-your-theme/stencil-utils-api-reference#stencil-utils_product

Comment: @KarenWhite looks like having to use the utils and call each product one at a time - thanks for the help!